# How do I sort string arrays or convert IEnumerable<string> to string array?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq, ienumerable

I'm trying to sort files into string arrays of extension .RAR and .ZIP to save for later usage. The args parameter will be usually be strings of filepaths and may differ in count.

eg.

```
args = {"..\test1.rar", "..\test2.rar", "..\source.txt", "..\randomfile.exe", "test3.zip"}
```

This code

```
public void ValidateFiles(string[] args) {
    var validRar = from item in args
        where Path.GetExtension(item) == ".rar" || Path.GetExtension(item) == ".r00"
        select item;
    var validZip = from item in args
        where Path.GetExtension(item) == ".zip"
        select item;

    //do some more stuff 
}
```

makes `validRar` and `validZip` of type `IEnumerable<string>`. How do I sort them to `string[]` instead?

Optimal result would be

```
string[] validRar = {"test1.rar", "test2.rar"}
string[] validZip = {"test3.zip"}
```

Comment: Just call `ToArray()` on the returned `IEnumerable<string>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to call `ToArray`:

```
public void ValidateFiles(string[] args)
{

    var validRar = (from item in args
        where Path.GetExtension(item) == ".rar" ||
              Path.GetExtension(item) == ".r00"
        select item).ToArray();
    var validZip = (from item in args
        where Path.GetExtension(item) == ".zip"
        select item).ToArray();

//do some more stuff 
}
```

Now, both `validRar` and `validZip` are `string[]`.

Comment: Thank you. Very simple solution. Before I posted I tried calling .ToArray  on item which left me with char. Missed those parentheses. xD

Comment: @LuRRE Yeah, thats why dasblinkenlight's recommendation on using fluent syntax is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

A way to convert `IEnumerable<T>` to an array `T[]` is to call `ToArray()` on it:

```
var validRarArray = (from item in args
    where Path.GetExtension(item) == ".rar" || Path.GetExtension(item) == ".r00"
    select item).ToArray();
```

It is easier to do when you use fluent syntax in place of the query syntax:

```
var validRarArray = args
    .Where(item => Path.GetExtension(item) == ".rar" || Path.GetExtension(item) == ".r00")
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an extension method to slice arrays:

```
public static T[] Categorize<T>(this T[] data, string extensions[])
{
    //using List to make copying easier
    List<T> result = new List<T>();

    foreach(string extension in extensions)
    {    
        var filteredData = (from item in data
                            where Path.GetExtension(item) == extension
                            select item)
        result.AddRange(filteredData);
    }

    return result.ToArray();
}
```

And call it like:

```
public void ValidateFiles(string[] args){
    var rarArray = args.Categorize<string>(new string[] {"rar", ".r00"});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `Array.FindAll` twice :

```
string[] validRar = Array.FindAll(args, f => Path.GetExtension(f) == ".rar" || Path.GetExtension(f) == ".r00");
string[] validZip = Array.FindAll(args, f => Path.GetExtension(f) == ".zip");
```